# How do the Americas Cup Yachts sails work?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

With the vast majority of sailing boats its pretty evident how the sails work to harness the energy of the wind to propel themselves forward. However on the modern Americas cup foiling yachts i can't seem to understand how you can be going more than twice the speed of the wind. I have tried to work it out myself by looking at airplane wings as they are essentially the same as these sails but obviously if an airplane could harness the wind like these sails do then we could fly round the world with no engine at all.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that since the switch to catamarans, the boats component of velocity in the direction of the wind (or opposite) can be faster than the wind (the boat has to be moving at an angle with the wind, not directly downwind). Take look at the wiki high performance sailing article in section [velocity made good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-performance_sailing#Velocity_made_good_(VMG)).

Answer (score 2):

Just look at it as a wedge.

To a 0th approximation, a sail or wing through fluid is just like a knife through jello.
It can only move along a line.

A sailboat has two of those.
It has a sail cutting through the air, and it has a keel (centerboard, leeboard, hull) cutting through the water.
Neither one of those can move sideways in its fluid, so if the air moves some distance over the water, the boat has to move also.
It's just like squeezing a greased wedge.

[image]

You see, if the slant of the sail is *very close* to the centerline of the boat, there is no limit to how fast the boat can go, if it had no drag.
But it does have drag, which is what limits it.

Notice the boat does not have to be going directly cross-wind.
The arrow of wind can be going in any direction, as long as it is not aligned with the boat.

P.S. Aircraft are different, because they are only traveling through one fluid, not two.

Comment: Well, to be precise, aircraft have no "keel" is why it doesn't work :-)

Comment: @Carl: Well, they sort of do, actually.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Keels/daggerboards/iceboat blades/skateboard wheels  all interface to that 'other fluid', or to solid surface.  Aside from gravity, aircraft sans propulsion can only float with the wind.

Comment: @Carl: The key is that 'other fluid'. Aircraft are built to resist sideways motion through the air, so you might call that a 'keel'. But as you say, they can't extract power from the wind. I take that back - if they are flying in an area of wind shear, they can. Some radio-controlled gliders have reached crazy speeds by doing vertical loops on the lee side of a hill.

Comment: @Carl: [*Glider speed record*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFPJ6DUAY10).

Answer (score 2):

This is not limited to hydrofoil hulls.  You can sail across the wind ("reaching") on other low-drag shapes such as windsurfers at speeds greater than the windspeed.  The fastest such craft, so far as I've heard, are iceboats -- which are sort of an ultimate "hydrofoil," in that they skate along the frozen lake surface with almost no friction at all.

Anyway, the reason this works is that it's only the virtual wind direction at the sail that matters.  On a broad reach (aka going almost perpendicular to the true wind direction),  the ice-boat will continue to gain speed so long as the true wind exerts force on the sail.  The vector diagram in MikeD's answer should  make it clear how it happens.   However, if you sail parallel to the wind, then once you reach wind speed, clearly the wind cannot provide additional force.

Now, for real fun, google around for  "DDWFTTW", or 'dead downwind faster than the wind', which can only be achived on land, and in an unobvious manner.

Comment: ++ for DWFTTW :) The car can go directly downwind, but the sails (the rotary wings) are going at an angle. In fact, I think it can also go upwind faster than the wind.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey - for DDWFTTW (first word is directly) carts, propellers are used because they are efficient. It's not necessary for the thrust generating device to have a component perpendicular to the wind, other than such devices are not as efficient as propellers. From the cart's frame of reference once at or beyond true wind speed, the ground is moving faster than the air, so reduction gearing can be used to multiply the force while dividing the speed. The increase in force is enough to compensate for losses, and achieve greater than wind speed.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey - and yes, directly upwind faster than the wind has been done with the [blackbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackbird_(land_yacht)) .